# wy is the function insert() cant insert (+,/,*,-,%,.)sign

Tags: javascript, php

I built this calculator with js and html and it work fine ,but when I put the code inside php in echo statement the(+,-,*,/,%,.)signs doesnt work i dont know why?I mean it should dipslay the number and the signs inside the textview the number are fine but the signs doesnt work

```
<?php echo"
<div class='wrap'>
  <form name='form' class='former' action='php/bill.php' method='GET'>
    <input class='textview' name='total' value='".$total."' placeholder='مجموع مشترياتك' readonly>
    <input type='text' name='ID' value='".$ID."' hidden>
    <input type='text' name='name' value='".$name."' hidden>
    <input type='text' name='page' value='".$row['href']."' hidden>
    <br>
    <button class='submit' type='submit' name='submit'>جد</button>
  </form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><input class='button' id='c' type='button' value='C' onclick='clean()'></td>
      <td><input class='button' type='button' value='<' onclick='back()'></td>
      <td><input class='button' type='button' value='%' onclick='insert('%')'></td>//here is th problem
      <td><input class='button' type='button' value='/' onclick='insert('/')'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class='button' type='button' value='7' onclick='insert(7)'></td>
      <td><input class='button' type='button' value='8' onclick='insert(8)'></td>
      <td><input class='button' type='button' value='9' onclick='insert(9)'></td>
      <td><input class='button' type='button' value='×' onclick='insert('*')'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class='button' type='button' value='4' onclick='insert(4)'></td>
      <td><input class='button' type='button' value='5' onclick='insert(5)'></td>
      <td><input class='button' type='button' value='6' onclick='insert(6)'></td>
      <td><input class='button' type='button' value='-' onclick='insert('-')'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class='button' type='button' value='1' onclick='insert(1)'></td>
      <td><input class='button' type='button' value='2' onclick='insert(2)'></td>
      <td><input class='button' type='button' value='3' onclick='insert(3)'></td>
      <td><input class='button' type='button' value='+' onclick='insert('+')'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan='2'><input class='button' type='button' style='width:106' value='0' onclick='insert(0)'></td>
      <td><input class='button' type='button' value='.' onclick='insert('.')'></td>
      <td><input class='button' type='button' value='=' onclick='equal()'></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>";
?>
```

and this is the javascript code

```
function insert(num){
            document.form.total.value = document.form.total.value+num;
        }
        function equal(){
            var ex = document.form.total.value;
            if(ex){
               document.form.total.value =eval(ex); 
            }
        }
        function clean(){
            document.form.total.value = "";
        }
        function back(){
            var ex = document.form.total.value;
            document.form.total.value = ex.substring(0,ex.length-1);
        }
        function forward(){
            var ex = document.form.total.value;
            document.form.total.value = ex.substring(0,ex.length+1);
        }
```

just for know every thing work fine just th signe are not

Comment: Please add the PHP code.

Comment: How is this a "php" question?

Comment: Could you minify the code to show the exact line of code that is having an issue- and show the error text as well?

Comment: Sohail gave you the right answer: there is a conflict with your quotes

Comment: the php coed is the same just inside echo statemnet like that echo"the code";

Comment: you have to use https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: please use `&#37;` instead of `%`, `&lt;` instead of `<`, `onclick='insert(\'*\')'` insted of `onclick='insert('*')'`, `'insert(\'+\')'` instead of `'insert('+')'` and `'insert(\'.\')'` instead of `'insert('.')'`

Answer (score 2):

Please use the double quotes after the `onclick` attribute. Currentlt browser is treating `onlclick` function like `onclick='insert('` .

Working code.

```js
function insert(num) {
        document.form.total.value = document.form.total.value + num;
      }
      function equal() {
        var ex = document.form.total.value;
        if (ex) {
          document.form.total.value = eval(ex);
        }
      }
      function clean() {
        document.form.total.value = "";
      }
      function back() {
        var ex = document.form.total.value;
        document.form.total.value = ex.substring(0, ex.length - 1);
      }
      function forward() {
        var ex = document.form.total.value;
        document.form.total.value = ex.substring(0, ex.length + 1);
      }
```

```html
 <div class="wrap">
      <form name="form" class="former" action="php/bill.php" method="GET">
        <input
          class="textview"
          name="total"
          value=''
          placeholder="مجموع مشترياتك"
          readonly
        />
        <input type="text" name="ID" value='".$ID."' hidden />
        <input type="text" name="name" value='".$name."' hidden />
        <input type='text' name='page' value='".$row['href']."' hidden>
        <br />
        <button class="submit" type="submit" name="submit">جد</button>
      </form>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input
              class="button"
              id="c"
              type="button"
              value="C"
              onclick="clean()"
            />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class="button" type="button" value="<" onclick="back()" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class='button' type='button' value='%' onclick="insert('%')">
          </td>
          //here is th problem
          <td>
            <input class='button' type='button' value='/' onclick="insert('/')">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input class="button" type="button" value="7" onclick="insert(7)" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class="button" type="button" value="8" onclick="insert(8)" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class="button" type="button" value="9" onclick="insert(9)" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class='button' type='button' value='×' onclick="insert('*')">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input class="button" type="button" value="4" onclick="insert(4)" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class="button" type="button" value="5" onclick="insert(5)" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class="button" type="button" value="6" onclick="insert(6)" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class='button' type='button' value='-' onclick="insert('-')">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input class="button" type="button" value="1" onclick="insert(1)" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class="button" type="button" value="2" onclick="insert(2)" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class="button" type="button" value="3" onclick="insert(3)" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class='button' type='button' value='+' onclick="insert('+')">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <input
              class="button"
              type="button"
              style="width:106"
              value="0"
              onclick="insert(0)"
            />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class='button' type='button' value='.' onclick="insert('.')">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class="button" type="button" value="=" onclick="equal()" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: it doesnt work the same sa before the signs still dosent show up @Sohail

Comment: I have added the full working code, Please try this.

Comment: If you use this html inside the echo statement `echo"` then you have to escape all double quotes inside the echo statement. e.g. `<input class=\'button' type='button' value='/' onclick=\"insert('/')\">

Comment: thank u very much, it worked just perfect,I appreiciate it @Sohail

Comment: @Mohammadhamad Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work and do likewise for your other questions.